# How can I automatically kick-off deployment of a VS database project after the deployment of another database project

Tags: sql-server-2008, deployment, msbuild, database-project, visual-studio-dbpro

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution containing 2 database projects, the primary project is a SQL Server 2005 database project, the secondary project is a 2008 database project.  The main 2005 project is deployed when you deploy the solution, however I would like this to also then deploy the 2008 project.

Currently I have to do the second project by hand and as a result sometimes forget to deploy it.

I reckon this must be achievable with a bit of MSBuild but could do with some pointers!!

Sam : )

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio go to `Build > Configuration Manager`.  There should be a `Deploy` option to enable/disable deployment of each database project.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I gave this a go but weirdly it doesn't solve my problem (although I believe it should!) - When configuring it like this the second deployment always fails and is skipped.  If I deploy the second project by hand then everything works perfectly.

I've looked at the messages but it doesnt give any information on what might be causing the failure, I'm going to have a look for some more detailed logs so I can figure out whats happening.